How do I type annotate a variable that stores a type annotation?
Suppose I have:
x: type = Optional[str] # <--- type error

This results in the type error:
Expression of type "UnionType" is incompatible with declared type "type"
  "UnionType" is incompatible with "type"

I do not want to type annotate x with typing.UnionType, becuase in general it could be any annotation. For example:
x: ? = NamedTuple
x: ? = MyClass
x: ? = str
x: ? = Any

Whatever I put down for ? should work for a broad class of type annotations. Do I have any good options beyond Any?

Given that types don't exist at runtime, how would "having a variable that stores a type annotation" even make sense? When performing type analysis there are no "stored  values" and by the time there are, there are no types.

You could always use object but as Mike pointed out, it doesn't really make sense to store these in variables.

What exactly is Optional?

@Lucenaposition It's typing.Optional.

I believe what you're looking is TypeAlias, or in python3.12 or later forming a type statement. This type allows you to say "this is an object with a type that's another type":
Before 3.12, you would say:
from typing import TypeAlias

x: TypeAlias = Optional[str]
x: TypeAlias = NamedTuple
x: TypeAlias = MyClass
x: TypeAlias = str
x: TypeAlias = Any

In 3.12 or later however this syntax was deprecated in favour of:
from typing import TypeAlias

type x = Optional[str]
type x = NamedTuple
type x = MyClass
type x = str
type x = Any

...but these two syntaxes equate to the same typing construct. Hope this helps!

TypeAlias is for symbols used as annotations. I believe OP wants to use Optional[str] as a value (e.g. print(Optional[str])).
